# Should I be concerned about lightning hitting my balcony antennas?

Tags: electricity, lightning

I want to put three antennas on my balcony (first floor, separate building): two for LTE connection (1800/1900 MHz, if that matters) and one for ADS-B capture (1090 MHz).

Should I be afraid (concerned) about direct lightning hit in this case? Can such antennas increase chance of lightning hitting my house? Or are such constructions irrelevant to storm and lightning?

Comment: Informative article here:  http://www.astronwireless.com/topic-archives-antenna-lightning-protection.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on where you live. If it's the top of a hill with no higher conductive objects around, then a definite "maybe". It it is situated in a dense urban area then probably not. In my area with dense low housing many people have satellite dishes screwed high on their outside walls, and I have never heard of any being struck by lightning in the area over a 25 year period.

Comment: That does not mean that they will not be struck one day.

Comment: True, but there is a greater chance of the house being struck first. There's not much defence against a direct lightning strike, even if you have a lightning rod, which the overwhelming majority of buildings do not have